# JSQMessagesViewController message observer duplicating messages

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a simple application using firebase.  You login and it takes you to a chatroom / channel board where you can select the topic you would like to post in.
Everything works perfectly, writes to firebase, updates the message board.

The issue comes in after you post in one topic, back out (segue) and then select a different or same topic to post in.  It duplicates (or triplicates depending on the number of times you exist and go back in) on the message board, but only writes to firebase the one time.

I tried to messages.removeAll() on Load, but it did not help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I can offer more help if there are some code but from your problem I think the reason is you did not clear observer before back out of topic. Something like this:

```
    conversationReference = Database.database().reference().child("conversations/{conversationId}")
    //observe messages ...

    //then before moving out
    conversationReference.removeAllObservers()
```